# Dynamic sum in dax picking distinct values

Tags: excel, business-intelligence, powerpivot, dax

Below is sample data

```
Week Practice  Type capacity   Gen
1       BI      c       80      0
1       BI      c       80      1
1       BI      sc      160     1
1       BI      pc      240     0
1       BI      pc      240     3
1       BI      mc      1160    1
1       BI      mc      1160    4
1       BI      mc      1160    2
1       BI      ac      440     1
1       BI      d       40      0
1       BI      d       40      3
```

I have a pivot chart, that has 3 slicers namely PRactice, Type, and gen.

when I don't select any slicer, it should be a distinct sum(capacity) ie.,2120. Then when I click on type slicer say mc Sum(capacity) should be 1160 and click on only gen say 3 and clear other filters then `sum(capacity) = 280`.

There can be many practices and many weeks.

Need dax query to meet this requirement.

Comment: Hi, what you mean by DISTINCT sum?

Comment: Yes, distinct sum according to the filter I select on slicer(Practice,type,Gen) and if no filter is selected then also it should be a distinct sum for the unique combination of Practice and Type (80+160+240+1160+440+40)

Comment: is capacity for type be always the same (meaning *mc* stays 1160 no matter what)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define two DAX measures:

```
Support:=MAX(Table1[capacity])
```

and

```
DistinctSumOfCapacity:=SUMX(DISTINCT(Table1[Type]),[Support])
```

Now you can add `DistinctSumOfCapacity` to the value section of your pivot and you'll get the distinct sum.

Comment: Peter, I am still a bit struggling with distinct sum -- how would that work for *GEN* column?

Comment: Similar - just add two more measures - and replace the `[capacity]` in the copy of `Support` with `[Gen]`...

Answer (score 1):

```
UniqSum = Divide (sum(table [Part] ), counta (table [part]) )
```

Or

```
UniqSum = Divide (sumx(table,table [Part] ), counta (table [part]) )
```