# DAX - Distinct SUM thru 2 dimensions

Tags: excel, sum, distinct, powerpivot, dax

I am trying to calculate "Distinct Sum" in DAX Powerpivot. I already have found help here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613333/dynamic-sum-in-dax-picking-distinct-values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjxtk.jpg)

And my  query is similar but extended further. I am seeking to find solution for such distinct Sum, but via two additional dimension (Month + Country)

In data example below there is Revenue performance on Part Number granularity. in Data there is also Shop Dimension, however Revenue is repeating on shops, is duplicated.

In the post mentioned above there is following solution:

```
Support:=MAX(Table1[Revenue])
DistinctSumOfRev:=SUMX(DISTINCT(Table1[Part_Num]),[Support])
```

It is work perfectly if you use Filter/Column/Row: Country and Month.
But if aggregate for All countries, or show performance on whole quarter, then solution will set MAX Revenue thru all countries/Months for and Part Number, which is not correct.

How to include into above solution also those two additional dimensions.
Basically to tell DAX that unique combination is PartNum+Country+Month

```
Country Month   Part_Num    Shop    Revenue
----------------------------------------
UK      1       ABCD        X       1000
France  1       ABCD        X        500
France  1       ABCD        Y        500
UK      2       ABCD        X       1500
UK      2       ABCD        Y       1500
UK      1       FGHJ        X       3000
France  1       FGHJ        X        600
UK      2       FGHJ        X       2000
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a calculated column to your `Table1`:

```
PartNumCountryMonth = [Part_Num]&[Country]&[Month]
```

Then create your measure as follows:

```
DistinctSumOfRev:=SUMX(DISTINCT(Table1[PartNumCountryMonth]),[Support])
```

### Update

Alternative solution, calculated column is **NOT** required:

```
DistinctSumOfRev :=
SUMX ( SUMMARIZE ( 'Table1', [Country], [Part_Num], [Month] ), [Support] )
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about concatenating those fields. Still curious to see if there is another, solution. Will try this one and let you know. Generally should work.

Comment: @milanminarovic, I've added an alternative solution to my answer where calculated column is not required. I don't like to mess my measures with tables calculations but this would be easier in this case though.

Comment: I have just use first solution with New concatenated column and it works as expected. Thanks